# Xamarin Visual Studio Mac AndroidX Problem

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, androidx, visual-studio-mac

I want to migrate my application to androidx. However, this line gives an error. The error is /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error AMM0000: Attribute category # $ {Myapp} @name at AndroidManifest.xml: 35: 19-59 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for  is provided. (AMM0000) (Myapp.Android)

```
<ManifestMerger
  ToolPath="$(JavaToolPath)"
  JavaOptions="$(JavaOptions)"
  ManifestMergerJarPath="$(AndroidManifestMergerJarPath)"
  AndroidManifest="$(IntermediateOutputPath)AndroidManifest.xml"
  OutputManifestFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\AndroidManifest.xml"
  LibraryManifestFiles="@(ExtractedManifestDocuments)"
  ManifestPlaceholders="$(AndroidManifestPlaceholders)"
  ManifestOverlayFiles="@(AndroidManifestOverlay)"
/>
```

Comment: According to your error message, I suggest you can try to add [AndroidManifestPlaceholders](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/114691/where-do-i-add-androidmanifestplaceholders-build-variables)

Comment: <PropertyGroup> <AndroidManifestPlaceholders>appAuthRedirectScheme=''</AndroidManifestPlaceholders> </PropertyGroup> i added this code on manifest.xml. but not worked

Comment: searching some info, try to clean and build your project gain.